# How to foreach array in mysql stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, loops, stored-procedures, foreach

I just studied Mysql stored procedures. I tried to create an array, and used a loop to handle each row in the array, it's like Foreach in PHP , but how to use it in Mysql stored procedure

```
BEGIN

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS final_late;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE final_late(staff_id int, total_late_count int, total_late_time int, month int, year int);

SET @work_staff = 'SELECT * FROM work_staffs WHERE staff_id = p_staff_id';

//example i want
WHILE (@work_staff as item) DO
//How to get row item like foreach in php (in php: item->column)
END WHILE;

END
```

Comment: SQL does not have the concept of arrays, nor can you throw a result set into a variable. SQL has tables and at a stretch cursors.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Normally you'd just run the SQL action with the result e.g. `update work_staffs set column = column + 1 WHERE staff_id = p_staff_id`

Comment: I want to calculate the total condition of a column and have 30 lines. the select statement will return a 30-line data set, I need to set up on each line to consider the condition and sum it up for the final result

Comment: You could improve this question by adding sample data and expected output as text to the question.

Comment: Sounds like this could be done with aggregation and doesn't need a procedural loop at all. I.e. use the "database way", which is usually far more efficient. You should describe what you actually want to calculate to get help on this.

Comment: thank for all, The cursor helped me solve the problem !